# What means "equal" in Euclid 4th postulate?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, axioms

In his 5 postulates Euclid said:"All the right angles are equal". What he really meant by that ? Does he meant that we can impose any right angle on each other or the meaning there was that if you find this angle through the length of arc and radius of the circle then you get the same number ? I also heard that this postulate can be proven (and I remembered that I saw such a question there, but now I can't find it). So what is the proof (based on the definition of a right angle like right angle is an angle which is equal to its adjacent angle)

Comment: See [here](https://plus.maths.org/content/maths-minute-euclids-fourth-axiom), for example.

Comment: Equal means congruent.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Moische Cohen equal should be interpreted as congruent. Further congruent is an undefined term in Hilbert's geometry. Note the there are two different undefined  congruence notions, one for segments the other for angles.

Comment: Isn't the definition of congruency of angles - an equality of angle measure ?

Comment: There is no definition in an axiomatic system like Euclid or Hilbert. But in other systems maybe based on analysis, such a definition as you suggest is possible.

Comment: One can turn that question and ask isn't the definition of measure equality of angles that they are congruent?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus OK, and if there is no definition of a congruency in axiomatic system, then there must be an axiom in Hilbert's system about congruency of angles, but as I know there is no.

Comment: Hilbert has two axioms with angle congruence, one that  says you can copy angles to congruent angles, and the SAS axiom for triangles. The latter makes a connection between the two congruence notions and allows assumptions about segments to be proved also for angles.

Comment: On the other hand Euclid choosed right angle as measure of others, but for doing this legitemetly he needed the fact that right angles are equal. In the same way we (using e.g. radians) say that the angles with angle measure of 1 radian are equal, so actually saying right angles are equal and saying that angles with angle measure of 1 radian are equal is the same thing (it's my hypothethis).