# Relationship between Axiomatic geometry and Hyperbolic geometry

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, axioms

I have done quite a bit of hyperbolic geometry and euclidean geometry, but one thing remained obscure to me throughout: the connection between axioms and the metrical definition of geometry.

As I learned it, hyperbolic geometry was constructed as a counterexample to the fact that the Parallel Postulate can be derived from the previous Euclidean axioms. This makes sense - clearly, given a line and a point, infinitely many non-intersecting lines through that point can be constructed.

But then I thought about the all right angles are equal axiom. Does this mean that all right triangles are isomorphic? If yes, doesn't this require a notion of distance on the Euclidean plane?

Given the hyperbolic infinite and spherical zero number of parallel lines, I soon wondered if there were geometries with exactly $2$ or $k$ lines parallel to a given line and passing through a point?
To solve this problem what constitutes, formally, a geometry/ how far can the term be reduced? I have seen definitions along the lines of $(P,l)$ for a point set P and line set $l$, but I do not see how this definition could be applied to solving the problem above.

Comment: You are asking two different questions here, which is never a good idea. An answer to the question about the angles can be found for instance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2627046/what-means-equal-in-euclid-4th-postulate?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: As for the other question, it's a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2726150/what-is-the-proof-of-infinite-number-of-parallel-lines-in-hyperbolic-geometry).

Comment: @MoisheKohan With respect to the first question, do I understand correctly from the linked answer that the notion of congruence is simply undefined?

Comment: @MoisheKohan The second question is $\textbf{not}$ answered in the given link. I understand full and well why there are infinitely many lines in hyperbolic geometry. The question was whether, there could be exactly two (or $k$, that is) lines parallel to a given line through a point. This question is still not answered and is contingent on the definition of what constitutes a geometry, which is why this question was also posed.

Comment: Not "undefined" but "primitive." Yes, the other question was not properly answered, but still is a duplicate. An answer is that you necessarily get the standard hyperbolic geometry once you add an axiom that there is a point and two lines parallel to the given line. I suggest you read a textbook on the subject. This will clear many misconceptions and answer your questions.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I read the entirety of Bonahon's Low Dimensional Geometry. I understand hyperbolic geometry. However, my question, refers to spaces in which there exist exactly two parallel lines through a given point parallel to a line. I have asked this question to my professor previously, and he has stated that he believes there may be pathological spaces in which this property holds, but was unable to provide an example, which is why I reached out to MSE. If this question is in fact a duplicate, feel free to point me to another question answering it.

Comment: In [absolute geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_geometry) (consisting of Hilbert's axioms for the Euclidean plane minus the Euclidean parallel postulate), it is a theorem that *if* there exists a line $L$, a point $P \not\in  L$, and two lines through $P$ disjoint from $L$ *then* for every line $L$ and every point $P \not\in L$ there exist infinitely many lines through $P$ disjoint from $L$.

Comment: If on the other hand you pare the axioms down much further, so that all you are talking about is an [incidence geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_(geometry)), then yes, there does exist an incidence geometry with a line $L$ and a point $P \not\in L$ and exactly two lines through $P$ disjoint from $L$.

Comment: Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!

Comment: Could you direct me towards a proof of the first result.

Comment: There are a bunch of books you might check, it might be in Hartshorne's book *Geometry: Euclid and beyond*.